# EnumProcessModulesEx fails returning error code 299 (ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY)

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, 64-bit, getlasterror

I am calling the function `EnumProcessModulesEx` and it fails. I running on a 64-bit machine. Here is the code below:

```
wchar_t* dest = new wchar_t[100];
int index = SendMessage(processes, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
SendMessage(processes, LB_GETTEXT, index, (LPARAM)dest);
HMODULE module;
unsigned long cbneeded;
EnableTokenPrivilege(hWnd, SE_DEBUG_NAME);
HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, _wtoi(dest));
int errorcode = GetLastError();
BOOL ret = EnumProcessModulesEx(h, &module, sizeof module, &cbneeded, LIST_MODULES_ALL);
int err = GetLastError();
wchar_t* name = new wchar_t[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleBaseName(h, module, name, sizeof name);
MessageBox(hWnd, name, L"Process Name", 0);
delete dest;
delete name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> BOOL ret = EnumProcessModulesEx(h, &module, sizeof module, &cbneeded, LIST_MODULES_ALL);

The 3rd argument is supposed to be the size of the *array* of HMODULES you pass in the 2nd argument.  You only pass 1, not big enough.  Note the lpcbNeeded, it tells you how large the array needs to be to not get the error.

Answer (score 6):

Most probably you are trying to open 32bit process from 64bit application or vice versa. You can only work with processes of the same kind.

Answer (score 1):

If the target platform is x86, then you can try to change it to x64.

You can read the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocessmodules

> If this function is called from a 32-bit application running on WOW64, it can only enumerate the modules of a 32-bit process. If the process is a 64-bit process, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299).

Answer (score 0):

Well, what does `GetLastError` return? EDIT: my bad, I failed hard..

Do error-checking and make sure it's not `SendMessage`, `EnableTokenPrivilege`, or `OpenProcess` that's giving you the error.